# Php_get_mysql_stat returns -1 va;ue for most of variables

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, percona, health-monitoring

**ss_get_mysql_stats.php** while running this script it returns most of the values result as -1. let's say in below command --item aa is innoDB pool size. Doing show variable status returns the correct value but this script returns -1.

Need help I'm stuck here from a long time because the same script is running fine on my other machine.

```
root@test:/home/graphs# /usr/bin/php -q /home/graphs/ss_get_mysql_stats.php --host localhost --items aa --user  --pass
aa:-1
root@test:/home/graphs#
```

note: I'm running mariadb and php version is **PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20**

Comment: No user?  What happens with `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` from the mysql commandline tool?

Comment: the user and pass has been passed in script. While running SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; it returns the correct values. In my case there is issue of only some values specially related to InnoDB